# Is it possible to change th owner of a group? (Solspace Friends module)

Tags: solspace-tag, solspace-friends

My client wants it to be possible for their members to change 'ownership' of groups in Friends module. Reason, say a member quits, or there is a problem. As far as I can figure out (docs) this is not possible, so we have a problem. I do hope someone has a good idea?

Comment: Sorry, that is currently not available. I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request for Friends. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on. :)
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions/forums/213806

Comment: Thanks for clearing this out for me. I do hope there is a new release in the making, actually my client says that the module is quite useless without this feature, so I am struggling to create a 'workaround'...